# What is the ASP.NET process for IIS 7.0?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Looking at what's running and nothing jumps out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be w3wp.exe

EDIT: In line with Darren's comment, you should also check the "Show processes from all users" in Task Manager if that is where you are looking for the process.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add something here, process explorer comes in handy when trying to track down a process:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Beats task manager hands down and can be substituted.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have show all processes checked (in vs)

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore if you need to look at the .NET/unmanaged stack just donwload [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and look at your w3wp.exe processes to examine memory and other stats without having to do a remote/local debugging (just look at the .NET Tab on the properties of the process). It will show all the .NET performance counters for that particular process.

Awesome tool!

Answer (score 0):

Using TaskManager should show you the process W3WP.exe is the IIS worker process, if you have multiple instances adding the Column "Command Line" will show you which Application Pool is being hosted on each of them in the -ap switch.
Also, in the IIS Manager UI there is a "Worker Processes" feature that if you double click that you will see the list of processes, Memory and CPU they are consuming, and double clicking the instance will show you the list of executing requests on it, really useful when trying to figure out a "misbehaving" request.